# Alternative to std::set_union with additional predicate parameter for merging elements from the intersection

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, std

Given two sorted containers and std::set_union, we can provide a predicate to determine when two elements are equal. I would like to provide an additional predicate that will merge the equal elements (the intersection of the containers) and insert the result into the output container.

Please note in the 'Expected output' section below how the vectors for set_union and unknown_func differ.

Is there a single algorithm that emulates the behavior described by the 'Expected output' below? If there are only more complex ways to have this behavior, can you please suggest where I may get started in doing so? Preferably the final solution only makes use of functionality provided by the std/stl libraries.

Sample Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct CustomStruct{
    CustomStruct(const int f1, const int f2) : field_1(f1), field_2(f2) {}
    int field_1;
    int field_2;
};

void print_vector(const std::string& str, const std::vector<CustomStruct>& vec){
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    for (const auto& val: vec){
        std::cout<< val.field_1 << ", " << val.field_2 << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<CustomStruct> vec_a;
    std::vector<CustomStruct> vec_b;
    std::vector<CustomStruct> vec_set_union;
    std::vector<CustomStruct> vec_unknown_func;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){ vec_a.emplace_back(i, 2); }
    for (int i = 2; i < 4; ++i){ vec_b.emplace_back(i, 3); }
    
    print_vector("VEC_A", vec_a);
    print_vector("VEC_B", vec_b);
    
    const auto compare = [](const CustomStruct& lhs, const CustomStruct& rhs){
        return lhs.field_1 < rhs.field_1;
    };
    std::set_union(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(),
                   vec_b.begin(), vec_b.end(),           
                   std::back_inserter(vec_set_union),
                   compare
   );
   
    print_vector("VEC_SET_UNION", vec_set_union);
    
    const auto merge_duplicate = [](const CustomStruct& lhs, const CustomStruct& rhs){
        return CustomStruct(lhs.field_1, lhs.field_2 + (rhs.field_2*rhs.field_2));
    };
    // std::unknown_func(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(),
    //                                     vec_b.begin(), vec_b.end(),           
    //                                     std::back_inserter(vec_unknown_func),
    //                                     compare,
    //                                     merge_duplicate
    // );
    
    // THE COMMENTED CODE ABOVE WOULD NEED TO ALLOW 'VEC_UNKNOWN_FUNC' to have
    // the 'Expected output' supplied as part of this question
    
    print_vector("VEC_UNKNOWN_FUNC", vec_unknown_func);
}
```

Expected output

```
VEC_A
0, 2
1, 2
2, 2
3, 2
VEC_B
2, 3
3, 3
VEC_SET_UNION
0, 2
1, 2
2, 2
3, 2
VEC_UNKNOWN_FUNC
0, 2
1, 2
2, 11
3, 11
```

Thanks for your time, let me know if I can give further clarifications.

Comment: So write a `set_union_transform` function that takes your `merge_duplicate` as another argument. What's the question?

Comment: Are you saying there is no simple way to handle this case by directly and exclusively using the standard library?

Comment: @acegene yes, we are saying that. `std` does not promise to hold every algorithm possible, but it does have some useful building blocks.

Comment: Your binary functor that merges two equivalent elements into a new element needs to have some well though out preconditions because there is a good chance that it will invalidate the sorted postcondition in the resulting vector

Comment: @AndyG good point. Easily could cause a headache if not considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Useless suggests in the comments, to do extra things over an `<algorithm>`, you should write something based on that algorithm.

Adapted from the [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union#Possible_implementation):

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2,
         class OutputIt, class Compare,
         class BinaryOp>
OutputIt set_union_transform(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                   InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                   OutputIt d_first, Compare comp,
                   BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    for (; first1 != last1; ++d_first) {
        if (first2 == last2)
            return std::copy(first1, last1, d_first);
        if (comp(*first2, *first1)) {
            *d_first = *first2++;
        } else if (comp(*first1, *first2)) {
            *d_first = *first1++;
        } else {
            *d_first = binary_op(*first1++, *first2++);
        }
    }
    return std::copy(first2, last2, d_first);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help on how to adapt content from `<algorithm>` for custom uses :)

Answer (score 1):

Just bashing at the keyboard but I think you want something like this:

```
std::vector<CustomStruct> vec_set_intersection1;
std::vector<CustomStruct> vec_set_intersection2;

// Find the duplicate objects in the first vector
std::set_intersection(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(),
    vec_b.begin(), vec_b.end(),           
    std::back_inserter(vec_set_intersection1),
    compare);

// Find the duplicate objects in the second vector
std::set_intersection(vec_b.begin(), vec_b.end(),
    vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(),           
    std::back_inserter(vec_set_intersection2),
    compare);

// Apply the transformation
std::transform(vec_set_intersection1.begin(), vec_set_intersection1.end(),
    vec_set_intersection2.begin(), vec_set_intersection2.end(),
    std::back_inserter(vec_unknown_func),
    merge_duplicate);
```

Comment: As I understand, this would properly transform the intersection, but not include the elements that are exclusive to each vector. However, it is interesting how this reverses the order of the params passed to each set_intersection call. This allows extraction of the values from each vector that are part of the intersection for use in the transform call, cool!